# How to group different cache in a cluster

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, jgroups, wildfly-cluster

Assume there are four instances of WildFly 8 running on two machines within the same network. Let's name them A, B, C and D. A, B runs on machine1 and C, D on machine2.

In case of UDP clustering it's working fine with multicast address.

Using TCP I face some issues in clustering. I want A, C to be considered one and B, D to be considered one. Consider A, C as transaction servers and B, D as report servers. A, C have cache name `lrpcache` and B, D have cache named `lrpcache1` and started with `ha` profile. When I start the server A, C is looking for the cache in B, D as they are in same cluster.

When I connect all I get the following warning:

> Discarding discovery request for cluster 'lrpcache1' from 54a568fd-b07a-dc68-01f3-0d978debf697; our cluster name is 'lrpcache'. Please separate your clusters cleanly.

I want A, C to work independent from B, D.

Servers were started as `standalone -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.x.x.x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique MPING address resolved this issue

Node A,C uses

```
<socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
```

Node B,D uses

```
<socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.5}" multicast-port="45700"/>
```

Thus A,C node doesn't lookup for cache in B,D

Comment: Hi Johnsi. If possible, accept your own answer so people know you have your issue solved. GL!